# Future dated record logic in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that has step details PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL. I have a process date column in table ess_request_history that is updated when we execute a job running this report.
The grade step details should be extracted when the latest update made on PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL is >= the last time the ess_request_history was executed.
For this i have created the below query-

```
select * from 
(
select grade_step_name,
grade_code,
grade_sequence,
Max(last_update_date) OVER( partition BY GRADE_STEP_ID) max_update_date
grade_effective_start_date
from PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL
where :effectivedate between grade_effective_start_date and  grade_effective_end_date
)
 where :attribute = 'N'
or (
  :attribute='Y'
  and max_update_date >=
    (
      (SELECT Max(processstart)
      FROM   fusion.ess_request_history erh,
             fusion.ess_request_property erp
      WHERE  erh.requestid = erp.requestid
      AND state = 12
      AND erp.NAME = 'reportID'
      ))
```

)

Currently, the query is functioning correctly; however, an issue arises when the `grade_effective_start_date` is a future date and the `max_update_date` is today's date. For instance, if the `grade_effective_start_date` is set to 01-Dec-2023, and the `max_update_date` is 16-Nov-2023, the query does not capture this scenario. I want to modify the query so that if the `grade_effective_start_date` is 01-Dec-2023, the query returns output when executed on 01-Dec-2023. The current logic, where the `max_update_date` is today's date, prevents it from being selected on 01-Dec-2023; instead, it gets selected on the current date.
How can I adjust the query to address this issue and ensure it works appropriately for future scenarios?

Comment: What is the value of ":effectivedate" on a given run? Intuitively I'd figure that'd be today's date, or whatever date you are controlling for. So if ":effectivedate" is 16-Nov-2023 on 16-Nov-2023, or any date earlier than 01-Dec-2023, you wouldn't pick up that future dated record based on between grade_effective_start_date and  grade_effective_end_date. But that must not be the case.

Comment: Another wrinkle to be wary of is that since these look like scd2 tables, if a future dated record had multiple upsert events while you were holding off on picking up you could miss those expired records entirely. Because they'd no longer satisfy between grade_effective_start_date and grade_effective_end_date.

Comment: You should find out what cases are possible and need to be covered. Then change your `WHERE` clause accordingly, for example using `OR` to make multiple conditions possible.

Comment: @Error_2646 :effectivedate will  be the date we are passing, which will be the sysdate by default. And you are right since we have between condition 01-dec-2023 will not be picked. which is why I am looking for a workaround

Comment: @Tech_Girl7819 Okay, got thrown off by "instead, it gets selected on the current date". I read that to be that the future dated record would get picked up earlier than it was effective. And ":attribute" must be some control for whether you are doing an incremental or full snapshot pull?

Comment: And since you'll have had processing in ess_request_history by the time 01-Dec-2023 rolls around you'd miss the record. Gotcha.

Comment: Could you change Max(last_update_date) OVER( partition BY GRADE_STEP_ID) to Max(greatest(last_update_date, grade_effective_start_date)) OVER( partition BY GRADE_STEP_ID)? That way it'll get picked up on 01-dec-2023, because it's greater than the true source table's update time. But not before because it wasn't effective yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the where condition as below:

```
 where :attribute = 'N'
   or (
      :attribute='Y'
      and least(max_update_date,grade_effective_start_date) >=
       (
        (SELECT Max(processstart)
         FROM   fusion.ess_request_history erh,
           fusion.ess_request_property erp
         WHERE  erh.requestid = erp.requestid
         AND state = 12 AND erp.NAME = 'reportID'
       ))
```

Comment: This will trigger it on the current date as well

Answer (score 0):

> an issue arises when the `grade_effective_start_date` is a future date and the `max_update_date` is today's date.

You appear to want to add filters for `grade_effective_start_date <= SYSDATE AND grade_effective_end_date >= SYSDATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT grade_step_name,
         grade_code,
         grade_sequence,
         MAX(last_update_date) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_step_id)
           AS max_update_date,
         grade_effective_start_date
  FROM   PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL
  WHERE  :effectivedate BETWEEN grade_effective_start_date
                            AND  grade_effective_end_date
)
WHERE  grade_effective_start_date <= SYSDATE
AND    grade_effective_end_date >= SYSDATE
AND    (  :attribute = 'N'
       OR (
              :attribute='Y'
          AND max_update_date >= (
                SELECT Max(processstart)
                FROM   fusion.ess_request_history erh
                       INNER JOIN fusion.ess_request_property erp
                       ON erh.requestid = erp.requestid
                WHERE  state = 12
                AND    erp.NAME = 'reportID'
              )
          )
       )
```

Are you sure the final part of the query is correct as there is no correlation between the outer query and the final sub-query so you are looking to see if there is any entry into the history table for any grade and are not checking to see if there was any recent entry into the history table for a specific grade?

Comment: the outer join query is to check last successfull run of the report, the date process date will pick up from there any changes made after that will only be picked in main query